# Connection a "Leves" in PA, USA in 1850 potentially to Levi routes in Alsace-Lorraine

Tags: germany, 18th-century, surnames, jewish, pennsylvania

My daughter's GGG grandfather, Thomas Levis, is 26 and located in Penn Forest, Carbon County PA in the 1850 census, but I haven't been able to get back any further. My daughter has half a clotting disorder gene that's significantly more strongly associated with Ashkenazi Jews that any other group, and when her grandmother (her father's mother) asked her dad about her Levis history, she always got a wink and a nod. There is a prominent Quaker Levis line that is traced from Philadelphia back to English royalty, and many Levis' in Ancestry connect Thomas to this family. His mother's name is listed as Mary Strohl in the Carbon County Advocate obituary (1874) and Maria in the 1860 census when she was living with Thomas. My husband has passed away, and his cousins have less knowledge than we do. There are so many variations on Levi in Pennsylvania that I thought I'd start with Levi, since I found nothing under Levis/Leves (both used - Thomas was a Leves, but after him most descendants used Levis perhaps because its connected to England). The elder generations spoke Pennsylvania Dutch with heavy German accents.
The only other piece of information I have is that most of his children's death certificates list Thomas' birthplace as simply Penna, but one listed towns for each parent and Thomas was born in Lehigh Gap, Penna; his wife Lydiann was born in Chestnut Hill 20 miles to the east. Thomas worked this his wife's father in the lumber business in Penn Forest, PA in 1850, and they were married at the time. I know it's a long shot, but do you have any ideas?